# Como enviar imagem para rota do laravel com AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Eu tenho uma rota POST comum no laravel, porem em um projeto separado eu gostaria de usar AJAX para enviar uma imagem para essa rota.
Eu vou usar o html2canvas para pegar a screenshot da tela.

```
var content = document.getElementById('welcome');

html2canvas(content, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        //AQUI FICA O AJAX
    }
});
```

Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso com AJAX??

Answer (score -1):

Você pode **[converter o canvas para imagem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)** e depois enviar via **["raw"](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input)**

Para converter o conteúdo para imagem, precisamos acessar a função **[toDataUrl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)** do canvas. Ela irá servir para transformar o objeto em um  **[base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)**.

Por padrão, você receberá uma imagem em `PNG`, porém, nada imagem que você possa escolher entre `JPEG` ou `WEBP`, por exemplo.

Outra que você também precisa ter em mente, é que por padrão, o **[jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** tenta converter os dados para `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` e não queremos isso. Queremos apenas enviar o conteúdo da imagem. Para isso *devemos* marcar como `false`, durante a configuração do jQuery.ajax.

Segue um exemplo para auxiliar o entendimento.

**Front-end:**

```
<h1 id="welcome">Hello Brazil!</h1>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
html2canvas( [ document.body ], {
    onrendered: function( canvas ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index2.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: canvas.toDataURL(), // Captura a imagem em base64
            contentType: 'image/png', // Informa o mime-type da imagem que por padrão é PNG
            processData: false //Informa ao jQuery.ajax para não converter os dados em application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

**Back-end:**

Como não sei o andamento do projeto, serei breve na parte de back-end.

Primeiro, devemos capturar esse `POST RAW`. No `PHP` fazemos isso passando o parâmetro `php://input` na função **[file_get_contents](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)**

Depois basta utilizar a função **[str_replace](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)** para substituir o mime-type que é adicionado ao converter de canvas para `base64`.

Feito isso, você terá sua imagem para utilizar em seu projeto.

Segue código para exemplificar.

```
<?php

$imageEncoded = str_replace("data:image/png;base64,", "", file_get_contents("php://input"));

$imageDecoded = base64_decode($imageEncoded);

// Salva a imagem
file_put_contents("image_screenshot.png", print_r($imageDecoded, true));
```